# Does a monotone sequence satisfying equality in weak inequality satisfy inequality onwards?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I have a relatively simple question in mind which I suspect to be true, but can neither prove nor disprove right now. It goes as follows:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be real weakly increasing monotonic sequence satisfying $a_{2n-1}\leq 4 a_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, I know that for some index $n_0$, we have $a_{2n_0-1}=4a_{n_0}$. ***Later edit**:* Assume also that $a_n\to \infty$.

Does this imply necassarily that $a_{2n-1}=4a_n$ for some $n$ onwards? Is it true if we assume that this inequality for a range of indices, e.g., for $n\in \{ 3,4,5,6,7 \}$? Or that the equality is true infintely often.

It seems to me like if there is an equality, this does not give the next indices too much freedom. Also in a specific sequence I looked at, I only had this estimate but it seemed like from some point onwards suddenly there was an equality.

I would appreciate any insight on the matter.

Comment: Just to be sure: A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is said to be weakly increasing iff $a_n \le a_{n+1}$ holds for all $n$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I see no reason why "the equality holds once" should imply that the equality will hold again at some (later) point in the sequence.

A counterexample is the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty = (1,1,4,4,4,4,4,\dots)$. It is increasing; the inequality $a_{2n-1} \le 4a_n$ is satisfied for all $n$; however equality $a_{2n-1} = 4a_n$ holds only for $n=2$.

**Edit**
OP added the condition that $a_n \to \infty$. Then I still see no reason why this should be true:

$$(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty = (1,1,4,5,6,7,8,\dots)$$

Comment: You're right, that was an oversight on my part.  I revised the question to include the appropriate assumptions. I appologize for that.

Comment: I have edited my answer. However, notice that it is a bit bad to edit your question substantially after someone has answered. Other people who stumble over the question will see my invalid answer (which had been valid when I wrote it) and put their energy in dealing with my mistake. I'm not sure however what to do instead: Maybe open a new question?

Comment: I agree that it is bad etiquette, but the original question was an omission on my part and was not good with that omission. I thinking opening a new question would be even worse, which is why I chose to edit it.